# Using dictionary to calculate totals from a text file in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, set

Below is a sample input file:

```
A,B,C 
Location:London 
A, 46
B, 93
C, 32
A, 48
Location:Amsterdam 
A, 83
B, 21
C, 92
B, 39
Location:Paris
A, 29
B, 91
C, 10
```

The output should be as follows:

name_set = { A, B, C } location_set = {London, Amsterdam, Paris}

Generate a dictonary that maps name to total:

dic = {A: 206, B: 244, C:134}

I was able to create different sets for location and name but I don't know how to get the total and generate a dictonary

```
name_set = set() 
location_set = set()
num_set = set ()
userfile = input("Enter input file name:") 
input_file2 = open(userfile, "r") 
input_file = input_file2.readlines()
name = input_file[0].strip().split(',') #get names from first line
name_set.update(name) 
for next_line in input_file: 
   if next_line.startswith('Location'): 
   location = next_line.strip().split(":")[-1] #get location 
   location_set.add(location) 

#calculate scores and totals (?) 

name_to_num = {}
for k in name: 
  for v in score: 
      name_to_num[k] = v #assign key (party name) to value (score)
print(str(name_to_num))
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary with the names as the keys and 0 for the values, and increment the appropriate value as you read the file.

```
userfile = "input.txt"
locations = set()
with open(userfile) as f:
    names = dict.fromkeys(next(f).strip().split(","), 0)
    location = ""
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Location:'):
            _, location = line.strip().split(":")
            locations.add(location)
        else:
            name, val = line.strip().split(", ")
            names[name] += int(val)

print(f"name_set = {set(names)} location_set = {locations}")
print(f"dic = {names}")
```

```
name_set = {'C', 'A', 'B'} location_set = {'Amsterdam', 'London', 'Paris'}
dic = {'A': 206, 'B': 244, 'C': 134}
```